# Como puedo dividir una lista en Mysql para separar entradas y salidas

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla que reguistra los tiempos guarda Num_Empleado, Checada, Terminal
genero el siguiente Query. La variable Terminal guarda 1,2 que es la vandera Entrada y Salida.

```
introducir el código aquí
 SELECT   
       e.Num_Emp,
       e.Nom_Empleado,
    CASE 
         WHEN  t.Terminal=1 IS NULL THEN "NoInfo" 
         WHEN  t.Terminal=1 THEN t.Checada END AS  "E", 
    CASE 
         WHEN  t.Terminal=2 IS NULL THEN "NoInfo" 
         WHEN  t.Terminal=2 THEN t.Checada END AS  "S", 
FROM employees_list e
LEFT JOIN  timeclok_2 t
    ON 
       t.Num_Emp=e.Num_Emp AND
       t.Checada >= '2023-04-24 00:00:00' AND 
       t.Checada <= '2023-04-25 23:59:59'
 WHERE 
    e.Estatus = 'Activo'      
GROUP BY  t.Empleado_No 
ORDER BY t.Checada ASC
```

Con esta consulta me arroja la informacion pero no me acomoda E/S me quita la primer consulta dejando solo la agrupacion del terminal 2

Comment: Preuba a agregar la terminal al grupo, es decir: `GROUP BY t.Empleado_No, t.Terminal`

Comment: Gracias, aparecen pero no hay forma para que aparescan en la misma linea?

Answer (score 0):

Eso ocurre porque no estás agrupando por `Terminal`.

Por otra parte, si quieres los valores de `E` y de `S` en una misma fila, deberás agrupar también, pero usando `GROUP_CONCAT`, combinado con `CONCAT` para colocar los valores que irá tomando la consulta según los casos se cumplan.

Además, debe haber un error o aquí: `t.Num_Emp=e.Num_Emp` o aquí `GROUP BY  t.Empleado_No`, parecería que es la misma columna de la tabla `timeclok_2`. En una parte le llamas `Num_Emp` y en otra parte le llamas `Empleado_No` ¿?

Finalmente, cuando usas `GROUP BY` debes poner en el grupo todas las columnas del `SELECT` que podrían no ser únicas, o indicar en la parte del `SELECT` cuál debe elegir el manejador en caso de que hubiera filas repetidas mediante funciones de agregación tipo `MIN`, `MAX` ... y lo mismo debes hacer si pones un `ORDER BY`. A veces sin hacer eso la consulta funciona, pero es porque en algunos entornos MySQL tiene el modo `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` desactivado. Esto es problemático, porque lleva a escribir consultas no estandarizadas y que en otros entornos SQL no van a funcionar (imagina que migras en un futuro a SQL Server, a Oracle u otro SGBD).

Aplicando todo lo dicho, el código quedaría así, te lo dejo en un fiddle completo:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE employees_list (
  Num_Emp INT,
  Nom_Empleado VARCHAR(150),
  Estatus VARCHAR(20)

);

CREATE TABLE timeclok_2 (
  Num_Emp INT,
  Checada DATETIME,
  Terminal INT
  
);


INSERT INTO employees_list VALUES (1,'Emp. 1','Activo');
INSERT INTO employees_list VALUES (2,'Emp. 2','Activo');
INSERT INTO employees_list VALUES (3,'Emp. 3','InActivo');
INSERT INTO employees_list VALUES (4,'Emp. 4','Activo');
INSERT INTO employees_list VALUES (5,'Emp. 5','InActivo');
INSERT INTO employees_list VALUES (6,'Emp. 6','Activo');
INSERT INTO employees_list VALUES (7,'Emp. 7','Activo');

INSERT INTO timeclok_2 VALUES (1,'2023-04-24 00:00:00',1);
INSERT INTO timeclok_2 VALUES (1,'2023-04-25 06:00:00',2);

INSERT INTO timeclok_2 VALUES (2,'2023-04-24 00:30:00',1);
INSERT INTO timeclok_2 VALUES (2,'2023-04-25 06:30:00',2);


INSERT INTO timeclok_2 VALUES (6,'2023-04-24 01:30:00',1);
INSERT INTO timeclok_2 VALUES (6,'2023-04-25 08:30:00',2); 

INSERT INTO timeclok_2 VALUES (7,'2023-04-24 02:30:00',1);
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT   
    e.Num_Emp,
    e.Nom_Empleado,
    GROUP_CONCAT(       
        CASE 
            WHEN  t.Terminal=1 IS NULL THEN 
                CONCAT("NoInfo") 
            WHEN  t.Terminal=1 THEN
                CONCAT(t.Checada) END 
      ORDER BY t.Checada ASC 
      SEPARATOR '|') AS  "E", 
    GROUP_CONCAT(               
        CASE 
            WHEN  t.Terminal=2 IS NULL THEN
                CONCAT("NoInfo") 
            WHEN  t.Terminal=2 THEN
                CONCAT(t.Checada) END 
      ORDER BY t.Checada ASC 
      SEPARATOR '|') AS  "S" 
FROM employees_list e
LEFT JOIN  timeclok_2 t
    ON 
       t.Num_Emp=e.Num_Emp AND
       t.Checada >= '2023-04-24 00:00:00' AND 
       t.Checada <= '2023-04-25 23:59:59'
 WHERE 
    e.Estatus = 'Activo'      
GROUP BY  e.Num_Emp,e.Nom_Empleado 
ORDER BY MIN(t.Checada);
```

| Num_Emp | Nom_Empleado | E | S |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Emp. 4 | NoInfo | NoInfo |
| 1 | Emp. 1 | 2023-04-24 00:00:00 | 2023-04-25 06:00:00 |
| 2 | Emp. 2 | 2023-04-24 00:30:00 | 2023-04-25 06:30:00 |
| 6 | Emp. 6 | 2023-04-24 01:30:00 | 2023-04-25 08:30:00 |
| 7 | Emp. 7 | 2023-04-24 02:30:00 |  |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mSPTHcgoiXvrC49P43io6B/0)

Comment: Son buenos tus puntos de vista... Gracias sera util.